# How do I iterate over an entire array of images before deciding if an image was found?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to iterate over an entire array of images and if any of them are found, I want to click `x`

If I get to the end of the array and none of them is found, I want to click `y` and then break out of the loop.

I can't figure out how to iterate over the entire array; this works but it iterates over the images sequentially, checking for a match, if it doesn't match it breaks out of the loop immediately without checking further images.

How do I check all of my images in my array for a match and then break out if none are found?

```
for image in image_list:
    found = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
    if Found != None:                                                    
            pyautogui.click(x)                                
    else:
            pyautogui.click(y)
            break
```

Full working code updated with details from the comments.

```
import os
import pyautogui as py
from PIL.ImageOps import grayscale

a = 0
aC = 0
image_list = []
# Get list of all files in current directory
directory = os.listdir()

# Find files that end with .png or .jpg and add to image_list
for file in directory:
    if file.endswith('.png'):
        image_list.append(file)

while True:
        if py.locateOnScreen('a.jpg') != None:
                breaking_bool = False
                while breaking_bool is False:
                    #Main Find Loop
                    for image in image_list:
                        name = image
                        Found = py.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
                        if Found != None:

                            py.moveTo(1700,1000,0.1)
                            py.sleep(0.01)
                            py.click()
                            py.sleep(1)
                            break
                        else:
                            py.moveTo(1415,1000,0.1)
                            py.sleep(0.01)
                            py.click()
                            py.sleep(1)
                            breaking_bool = True
                            
                    aC = aC + 1
                        
        a = a + 1
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation, otherwise people will think that the issue has to do with whitespace. Maybe it does if that's how your code really looks.

Comment: Fixed! Sorry, was an example I typed up rather than a copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case for the `for-else` loop.

The `else` block is evaluated when the loop runs without encountering a break statement.

```
for image in image_list:
    found = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
    if found != None:
        pyautogui.click(x)
        break
else:
    pyautogui.click(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of whether or not you found anything. Right now you have no way of keeping track of whether or not at least one image was found. Based on your requirements I think this will do what you want:

```
found_any = False
for image in image_list:
    found = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
    if found is not None:
        found_any = True
        pyautogui.click(x)
if not found_any:
    pyautogui.click(y)
```

If an image is found, x will be clicked for each found image. If no images are found, y will be clicked.

If you want to only click x once, then your code would look like:

```
found_any = False
for image in image_list:
    found = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
    if found is not None:
        found_any = True
if not found_any:
    pyautogui.click(y)
else:
    pyautogui.click(x)
```

Comment: I only want to click x once, will try that now. Thank you for the explanation that makes sense!

Comment: The else is triggering immediately with the second example. I'll update the OP showing my full code rather than just the example code.

Comment: Seems like `image_list` must be empty then. Unless your indentation is messed up. The `if` and `else` statements need to have the same indentation as the start of the `for` loop. Did you [debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) the program to see exactly how it executes?

Comment: Updated with my full code, does that help? I actually log and print out quite a lot that I've omitted from the above, image_list is definitely not empty. There's a dozen images in there at the moment.

Comment: Not really, all I can assume that's happening is that the indentation isn't correct. I think you'll have to step through it line-by-line in a debugger in order to see exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Absolutely right, image_list is empty. It wasn't last night. Will try and fix it and get back to see if your solution worked. Thank you!